# When using ARRAY_AGG it removes my record

Tags: u-sql, array-agg

I am trying to use Array_agg to help combine some records, but it seems to be removing the record when I try to use it. The format of what I have written is below. All the records which are individual stay.

```
SELECT 
columnA,
columnB,
columnC,
string.Join(", ", ARRAY_AGG(column1)) AS col1,
string.Join(", ", ARRAY_AGG(column2)) AS col2,
SUM(column3) AS col3,
SUM(column4) AS col4,
FROM table
GROUP BY columnA, columnB,columnC
```

Comment: Please add more info to your question. You mean you lost column1 and columns2 when you use your function? How you output this data?

Comment: Out putting as a CVSs. Within the data set there were two records which I wanted to combine because of column 1 and 2. However in the output they do not appear at all, combined or not!

Comment: can you show the example?